# Observable.create() subscribeOn and observeOn not working

Tags: java, android, multithreading, rx-java2

In my Android Application I used Rxjava2,But some strange situation was appeared.

In my   `Disposable`   I print to log current thread name:

```
    //1
    Observable
            .create((ObservableOnSubscribe<UserModel>) e -> {
                //mock io
                if (phoneNumber.equals("HolyHigh") && password.equals("111111")) {
                    e.onNext(new UserModel());
                    e.onComplete();
                } else {
                    e.onError(new RuntimeException("Error."));
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe(
                    r -> {
                        view.onLoginSuccess(new UserModel());
                        //test
                        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                        Log.e("Thread Name", " Success Current Thread Name: " + name);
                    }
                    , e -> {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        view.onLoginFailed(e.getMessage());
                        //test
                        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                        Log.e("Thread Name", " Error Current Thread Name: " + name);
                    }
            );
```

then logged:

`Thread Name:  Error Current Thread Name: RxComputationThreadPool-3`

It looks like observeOn and subscribeOn not working...
why not main thread?

However,I wrote some simple ...

```
//2
    Single.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(r -> {
                Log.e("Single Thread Name", "Single Thread Name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                CommonUtil.showToast(r + "~");
            });
```

and this logged:

`Single Thread Name: Single Thread Name: main`

where is my mistake?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delay()` operator operates by default on the computation scheduler, so it is changed upstream events to get notify on computation thread.

You simply need to change it right before the subscribe, just move the `observeOn .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` after the `delay()` operator.

BTW, `delay()` also has overload that gets `Scheduler` param that lets you change the default `Scheduler`.

Comment: Yes!Explain very clear. I move the ```observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) ``` after the ```delay()```,it worked! Thank you~